# How to use GroupByKey in Spark to calculate nonlinear-groupBy task

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregation

I have a table looks like

```
Time  ID  Value1  Value2 
 1    a     1      4
 2    a     2      3
 3    a     5      9
 1    b     6      2
 2    b     4      2 
 3    b     9      1
 4    b     2      5  
 1    c     4      7 
 2    c     2      0
```

Here is the tasks and requirements:

1. I want to set the column ID as the key, not the column Time, but I don't want to delete the column Time. Is there a way in Spark to set Primary Key?
2. The aggregation function is non-linear, which means you can not use "reduceByKey". All the data must be shuffled to one single node before calculation. For example, the aggregation function may looks like root N of the sum values, where N is the number of records (count) for each ID :

   ```
   output = root(sum(value1), count(*)) + root(sum(value2), count(*))
   ```

To make it clear, for ID="a", the aggregated output value should be

```
 output = root(1 + 2 + 5, 3) + root(4 + 3 + 9, 3)
```

the later 3 is because we have 3 record for a. For ID='b', it is:

```
 output = root(6 + 4 + 9 + 2, 4) + root(2 + 2 + 1 + 5, 4)
```

The combination is non-linear. Therefore, in order to get correct results, all the data with the same "ID" must be in one executor.

I checked UDF or Aggregator in Spark 2.0. Based on my understanding, they all assume "linear combination"

Is there a way to handle such nonlinear combination calculation? Especially, taking the advantage of parallel computing with Spark?

Comment: You can do a reduceByKey, producing the sum, and the count of the values, and then do root([sum], [count]) on it, can't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function you use doesn't require any special treatment. You can use plain SQL with `join`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{count, lit, sum, pow}

def root(l: Column, r: Column) = pow(l, lit(1) / r)

val out = root(sum($"value1"), count("*")) + root(sum($"value2"), count("*"))

df.groupBy("id").agg(out.alias("outcome")).join(df, Seq("id"))
```

or window functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("id")
val outw = root(sum($"value1").over(w), count("*").over(w)) + 
           root(sum($"value2").over(w), count("*").over(w))

df.withColumn("outcome", outw)
```